# JSON data doesn't load when send a request

Tags: java, android, json, android-studio, android-volley

Im trying to build a JSON request application .It takes params on earthquake from this website "https://earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/query". The problem im facing is that when the app Activity started just the progress bar is visible but no JSON data is shown nor textview is shown, just progressbar keeps on loading till the end. I tried but couldn't able to solve where the error is. Please help me, Im just stuck here for a couple of days. Thank you in Advance

My **Main Activity** code

```
package com.example.volleyearthquake;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.content.Context;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonArrayRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.json.JSONStringer;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;
    private ArrayList<Earthquake> mEarthquake;
    private RecyclerView mRecycleView;
    private EarthquakeAdapter adapter;

    boolean isConnected;
    /**
     * Textview to be displayed when the listview have no data
     */
    TextView emptyView;
    /**
     * Progressbar variable which is circular spinner (loading indicator)
     */
    ProgressBar loadingIndicator;
    private static final String USS_REQUEST_URL = "https://earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/query";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) this.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

        Read_network_state(cm);
        loadingIndicator = findViewById(R.id.loading_indicator);
        emptyView = findViewById(R.id.empty_view);

        mRecycleView = findViewById(R.id.recycle_list);
        mRecycleView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        LinearLayoutManager manager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        mRecycleView.setLayoutManager(manager);
        mEarthquake = new ArrayList<>();
        adapter = new EarthquakeAdapter(MainActivity.this, mEarthquake);

        mRecycleView.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        parseEarthquake();

    }

    private void parseEarthquake() {

        final JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, USS_REQUEST_URL,
                null, response -> {

            try {
                JSONArray feature = response.getJSONArray("features");
                for (int index = 0; index < feature.length(); index++) {
                    JSONObject features = feature.getJSONObject(index);
                    JSONObject properties = features.getJSONObject("properties");
                    Double magnitude = properties.getDouble("mag");
                    String location = properties.getString("place");
                    long time = properties.getLong("time");
                    String url = properties.getString("url");

                    mEarthquake.add(new Earthquake(magnitude, location, time, url));
                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }, error -> {

        });
        mRequestQueue.add(request);
    }

    public void Read_network_state(ConnectivityManager connectivityManager) {

        NetworkInfo activeNetwork = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (activeNetwork != null && activeNetwork.isConnectedOrConnecting()) {
            isConnected = true;
            Log.d("Ruhul", "CONNECTED TO INTERNET");
        } else {
            isConnected = false;
        }
    }
}
```

In Manifest File I have also added

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Comment: add `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` after `mEarthquake.add()` also watch your log cat if JSONException is thrown

Comment: Finally i solve it . The problem was in the URL i think that url was outdated so i use the new one( https://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/4.5_day.geojson) and now it is working fine. Thank you for your response

Answer (score 0):

Please check if there is a JSON Exception. Most probably, thats the reason that you are parsing incorrectly, Without checking your JSON response, it's hard to figure out if you are parsing stuff correctly.

Comment: I wrote it this way `catch (JSONException e) {
               Log.e("QueryUtils", "Problem parsing the earthquake JSON results", e);
           }` then i logcat it but when i search for "QueryUtils" in logcat nothing is shown up. I think i have done some mistake there, if i did then please shown me how to write and where to write. Im little bit new to android development

Answer (score 0):

put the   parseEarthquake(); above the
mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

like this

```
mRecycleView.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        parseEarthquake();
        mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
```

if dosetn work share your error pls.

Comment: After changing the code as you told above . App crash down with error             
 `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.android.volley.Request com.android.volley.RequestQueue.add(com.android.volley.Request)' on a null object reference
 at com.example.volleyearthquake.MainActivity.parseEarthquake(MainActivity.java:103)
        at com.example.volleyearthquake.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:69)`                   69 line was- parseEarthquake();   and 103 line was mRequestQueue.add(request);

Answer (score 0):

First you must parseEarthquakes, then put them inside the recyclerView,  if you still have an error, Try to trace your request step by step and check locat to ensure that you parse the json correctly and there is no errors while parsing it ,
hint: json does not cause a crash for application when some error happens while parsing it ... I hope that my answer helped you well ^_^

Comment: If you don't mind can you please show it. I'm little bit confused